Could Phobos or Deimos be a good target for mining?
Phobos could be loaded with iron, magnesium, and other metals of sorts. Because of the mineralogy of the moon, could it become a useful target for future plans similar to asteroid mining?
Phobos and Deimos to be visited and their samples collected in 2031, which could help determine possible mining opportunities in case they are comet remnants, as some ice can be seen in the picture below.


Phobos is a moon, so in the strict definition the answer to your question is "no". But of course it could be mined, like any other planet, moon, or asteroid.

@classOf2024 - re your edit, be careful assuming white material in a photo of space objects means water ice. The image is a false colour one and the material appears to be from the impact that made the crater https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stickney_(crater). Not relevant here but also careful of things like white CO2 showing up.

Phobos is not a particularly useful object for mining, at least short term (decades). The location and low escape velocity of Phobos also means care would be required that any attempt to mine it did not produce a debris ring/Kessler event in low Mars orbit.
It is fairly deep inside Mars' gravity well, so shipping metals to Earth or other locations is fuel intensive (at least 1 kilometer/second DV). Shipping from Moon to LEO is lower energy and much faster, and for other locations asteroids would seem easier to access. Shipping to mars surface is not hard, but since Phobos seems chemically similar to Mars mining the same material in situ is probably easier. It may be a way for Martin bases to access materials otherwise trapped deep beneath the surface, noting lack of volcanic activity or plate tectonics bringing deep material up but not enough is currently known about Mars, Phobos or hypothetical Martian bases to currently say*.
What would be useful in low mars orbit would be fuel and oxidizer, both for descent to mars and return to Earth, but it appears to be short on hydrogen compounds, and most viable rocket chemistries want large amounts of that. Water in particular would be useful but it appears warm enough that bulk ice will not exist.
In a much more distant future where humans on Mars might be looking to expand further out it would be a useful materials source for building space stations and orbital infrastructure, possibly including anchoring a space elevator.
In the shorter term it is most likely not particularly useful, though answer may change should a lander survive to get in samples.
*Diamonds and associated high temperature/pressure crystals are probably very rare in accessible Martian locations, and might be present on Phobos if it is actually an ejected chunk of proto Mars, but in absence of artificial forces Lab grown crystals will probably be meeting any Martian needs.

Can Phobos be spun up like a centrifuge for gravity, by mining it irregularly? Just came across this article theorizing that both Mars’s moons are remnants of a comet, which means it contains water/ice to refuel may be. https://www.yahoo.com/news/mars-moon-may-not-think-155815815.html

Or for Deimos which is far from Mars gravity well and smaller but could also be water based, could we hit it with another Dart probe to get it spinning with Coriolis Effect (similar to Ceres)  https://www.nasa.gov/news-release/nasa-confirms-dart-mission-impact-changed-asteroids-motion-in-space/

Spinning up Phobos would be very likely to cause a lot of loose material on the surface to come off and be flung into Mars orbit, which is the debris ring thing we'd like to avoid. Keep in mind that the escape velocity for Phobos varies between a brisk jog and an Olympic sprinter's top speed, depending on where you're standing, so it wouldn't take much force to generate a really big mess.

@estinamir Phobos weighs 10000000000000 tonnes. Getting spin onto that involves energy numbers in the same order of magnitude as humanities global electrical generation capacity and rotation rates of 'per day'. Nothing centrifugal happening there. Re water that only holds true if at no point since capture it has heated enough to melt, which may be true kilometers deep but anything usefully near the surface is long gone, even in the weaker sunlight at Mars.

Mining in space will be very different from terrestrial mining. Apart from the obvious issues related to gravity, the impact of water on geological chemistry and physics is immense. Even on moons & asteroids where water / ice is present, they won't have water-based erosion or alluvial concentration of minerals. We have all sorts of tricks for extracting important materials from a clay matrix, but that knowledge is useless when there's no processes creating clay. ;) Also, many mining & ore processing techniques rely on water. We will have to develop new techniques.

They appear to be carbonaceous chondrites, so NOT chemically similar to Mars -  like C type asteroids. Also DV between LEO and moon is ~5.7km/s - Deimos can be less at 5.3 (?). Such materials have significant carbon, carbon compounds and high water content (re Bennu samples and meteorites) with nickel-iron common as grains and sometimes nodules (chondrules). For making fuels for Mars missions I think it makes sense (if Mars makes sense). For refueling before landings and return legs. Near Earth orbiting asteroids would be better for commercial mining, having better solar power and less DV.

@KenFabian looks like they have updated assumptions on the origins again, though a good answer here waits on someone getting a lander onto one/both of them and hopefully getting subsurface composition. Also I think your five ish DV numbers are assuming rocket thrust, for payloads back from both Moon and mars you can achieve ~2.5 numbers with aerobrake/aerocapture, which may or may not come out ahead (eg if shipping bulk metals rather than people). Regardless you are correct that Deimos can have slightly lower DV numbers than the moon for same starting assumptions.
